# Having problems with concurrency while trying to lock a record in custom messaging system (Queue)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**We are building our own custom messaging system and are having concurrency issues. Here are the rules:**

1. **A process (EXE) console application locks 3 records and returns them**
2. **No other process running (we have 5 EXEs running) can pick any record that the other processes have already taken.**

That simple, but yet, I'm puzzled.

Summary of the SQL SPROC doing a "Lock And Peek":

The idea behind this that we reserve three "NEW" records and change their status to "IN PROGRESS" with a ROWLOCK on the SELECT and UPDATE statements. So in theory these records should be locked for one process so that other processes can't update or even select them. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LockAndPeek] 
    @Count INT,
    @QueueTypeId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ListofIDs TABLE(ID INT);
    DECLARE @StatusIDInProgress INT

    SELECT @StatusIDInProgress = ID FROM QueueStatuses (NOLOCK)
    WHERE Name = 'In Progress'

    INSERT INTO @ListofIDs
    (ID)
    SELECT TOP (@Count) Q.ID 
    FROM
        Queues Q (ROWLOCK) INNER JOIN
        QueueStatuses QS (ROWLOCK) ON Q.StatusID = QS.ID
    WHERE
        QS.Name IN ('New', 'Errored') AND
        Q.TypeID = @QueueTypeID AND
        Q.AvailableTime IS NOT NULL AND
        Q.AvailableTime <= GETUTCDATE()
    ORDER BY Q.ID

    UPDATE Q WITH (ROWLOCK)
    SET 
        STATUSID = @StatusIDInProgress,
        PROCESSED = GETUTCDATE()
    FROM
        Queues Q (ROWLOCK) INNER JOIN
        QueueStatuses QS (ROWLOCK) ON Q.StatusID = QS.ID INNER JOIN
        @ListofIDs LI ON Q.ID = LI.ID
    WHERE
        QS.Name IN ('New', 'Errored')

    SELECT  Q.ID, 
            Q.AvailableTime,
            Q.NumberOfTries,
            Q.Created,
            Q.Processed,
            Q.ErrorData,
            QT.ID QueueTypeID,
            QT.Name QueueTypeName,
            QS.ID QueueStatusID,
            QS.Name QueueStatusName,
            Q.Message
    FROM 
        Queues Q (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
        QueueStatuses QS (NOLOCK) ON Q.StatusID = QS.ID INNER JOIN
        QueueTypes QT (NOLOCK) ON Q.TypeId = QT.ID INNER JOIN
        @ListofIDs LI ON Q.ID = LI.ID

END
```

Comment: So are you expecting the `SELECT ... WITH (NOLOCK)` statements to *not* be able to read the `ROWLOCK`ed rows?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Why not just use SQL Server's built-in Queue mechanism, Service Broker?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx

Comment: All of the selects are WITH (ROWLOCK) except for the first one that I'm assigning the StatusIDInProgress variable... which I really don't care if it's locked or not... bAlso the last SELECT statement I don't really care about either, it's just the SELECT into the @ListOfIDs table variable and the update Queues table and both have ROWLOCK

Comment: @MaxVernon, I already did a POC for Windows Azure Service Bus and it was working fine... but then management decided to change it to a custom queuing system. To answer your question, I have no choice.

Comment: In the code above, the last select statements is returning one row for two different EXEs. Instead of returning one row to one EXE, and the second row to the second or subsequent EXE. I'm guessing that this has to do with LOCKING, because if I update WITH (ROWLOCK), then even if another process selects that row, the UPDATE checks to see if it's still new. But that's obviously not happening

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to atomically select-and-update rows so they don't get selected by other processes.  Perhaps this will help:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36773/10832

Comment: @MaxVernon, I don't see how that would apply to my situation. What they're doing is just increment the last ID, and inserting it to a table.

Comment: The point there is the ID is updated by one and only one process at a time.  I thought you might be able to adapt one of the answers to your particular problem.  Not exactly 100% straight forward, but probably enough to get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Big ups to @MaxVernon!

http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/ is basically a variation of what @MaxVernon posted as a comment. My query looks like this, so much simpler than before:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LockAndPeek] 
    @Count INT,
    @QueueTypeId INT
AS
BEGIN

SET XACT_ABORT ON; -- blow up the whole tran on any errors
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE Q
SET 
    StatusID = 2, -- In Progress
    Processed = GETUTCDATE()
OUTPUT Inserted.*
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (@Count) * 
    FROM
        Queues WITH (READPAST, ROWLOCK)
    WHERE
        StatusID = 1 AND -- New 
        TypeID = @QueueTypeID AND
        AvailableTime IS NOT NULL AND
        AvailableTime <= GETUTCDATE()
   ORDER BY ID
) Q;

COMMIT TRAN;

END
```